# Pandas series name

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I am trying to name my series "Points" but it is not showing up as Points.

```
Points = pd.Series([1,2,3])

print(Points.name)
output: None
```

I even tried renaming it but it still shows "None"

```
Points.rename("Points")
print(Points.name)
output: None
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong.  Do you already have some other variable named `pd` or `Series`?  Those would be the likely culprits.  Try quitting your interpreter and re-doing.

Comment: What @BradSolomon said!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Points is your variable assigned the your series.

```
Points = Points.rename("Points")
```

Not "s" in the above example.

```
print(Points)

0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: Points, dtype: int64
```

and

```
print(Points.name)

'Points'
```

Comment: My bad, i didn't write what i was experiencing problems with, it wasn't printing the series, but printing the name of the series.

Comment: @Ali Scott got it right anyway.  `Points.rename('Points')` returns a copy of `Points`.  You need to reassign to the name `Points` as he has shown.

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ScottBoston Sure, sorry i'm new to this site.