# How can I convert the name of a pandas series into a string?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I am writing a function where the argument is a `pandas` Series and I want to be able to print the name of the `pandas` series. Here is the function I have so far:

```
def chi2_ind_reps(x):
    if chi2_ind(df['n_killed'], x) is True:
        print('n_killed is dependent on ')
    if chi2_ind(df['n_injured'], x) is True:
        print('n_injured is dependent on ')
```

For example, I want `chi2_ind_reps(df['date'])` to return

```
n_killed is dependent on df['date']
n_injured is dependent on df['date']
```

I have tried to use the `str()` function but that would just return the entire series as string objects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can get the name of a pandas Series by using `s.name`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas series name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120478/pandas-series-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.name.html) attribute of the series.

Look also at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120478/pandas-series-name) for a similar case.

Comment: If you're linking another answer that says the same thing, it is better to flag as a duplicate, than post another answer.

Comment: @user3483203 ok, that makes sense. Added a flag as duplicate.